# Use Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties in Firebase Messaging Service on Xamarin.Android Native Level

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project. And used *Firebase Cloud Messaging* in Xamarin.Android Native Level.

I saved login details in `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` *Dictionary*.

After that, I used the same `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` in `OnMessageReceived` method of `com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT` Service.

Now `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` *Dictionary* is accessible when App is in Foreground or in Background **(But not killed)**. But, when App is **closed/killed by swiping the App to left/right**, `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` *Dictionary* **is not** accessible.

I tried to find out how `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` *Dictionary* can also be saved in Xamarin.Android `SharedPreferences` because it's **accessible even the App is killed,** but unable to succeed.

So, **Can I achieve this? And if yes then How?**

Comment: two years later and I have the same question as you. Can you share with us your solution?

Comment: @LeandroDeMelloFagundes sorry dear no solution found yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xamarin Essentials Package, it has a API for saving data in SharedPreferences.

You can see all the examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android).

Comment: Implemented also from Xamarin.Essentials Package but same result. Not working after App killed. Kindly suggest another way. I need urgent help.